# Кросскомпиляция rust из Linux в Windows

Tags: linux, windows, rust, кросс-компиляция

У меня Fedora Linux 31. Берём простейшую программу на Rust:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Она прекрасно компилируется как родная программа для Linux. Но когда я пытаюсь её кросскомпилировать с линуксового хоста под Windows ничего не получается.

Почитав англоязычный stackoverflow и достаточно погуглив я выполнил вроде как все рекомендации, про которые там говорилось. Я установил все необходимые цели в Rust:

```
[pfemidi@pfemidi hello_cargo]$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/pfemidi/.rustup

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

i686-pc-windows-gnu
i686-unknown-linux-gnu
i686-unknown-linux-musl
x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.39.0 (4560ea788 2019-11-04)

[pfemidi@pfemidi hello_cargo]$
```

Я установил компиляторы mingw32 для виндовых целей i686 и mingw64 для виндовых целей x86_64. Тестовая программа на C++ обоими компиляторами прекрасно компилируется, собирается и работает, то есть как 32-хбитный, так и 64-хбитный компилятор установилсь нормально:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Так же в .cargo/config я добавил необходимые строчки для вызова соответвующих линкера и библиотекаря для целей Windows, как 32-хбитных, так и 64-хбитных:

```
[target.i686-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "i686-w64-mingw32-gcc"
ar = "i686-w64-mingw32-ar"

[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc"
ar = "x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar"
```

Но когда я пытаюсь собрать хоть 32-хбитную цель Windows:

```
cargo build --release --target i686-pc-windows-gnu --verbose
```

хоть 64-хбитную:

```
cargo build --release --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --verbose
```

компиляция проходит нормально, но при сборке линкер жалуется на отсутствующие библиотеки (хотя в системе они есть, я проверял и перепроверял уже стопицот раз):

```
[pfemidi@pfemidi hello_cargo]$ cargo build --release --target i686-pc-windows-gnu --verbose
   Compiling hello_cargo v0.1.0 (/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo)
     Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name hello_cargo src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C panic=abort -C metadata=3801b83c24480675 -C extra-filename=-3801b83c24480675 --out-dir /home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps --target i686-pc-windows-gnu -C ar=i686-w64-mingw32-ar -C linker=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -L dependency=/home/r/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps -L dependency=/home/r/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/release/deps`
error: linking with `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "i686-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-Wl,--enable-long-section-names" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-nostdlib" "-Wl,--large-address-aware" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/crt2.o" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/rsbegin.o" "-L" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.hello_cargo.ejabbyqy-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.exe" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/hello_cargo-3801b83c24480675.3miif37looiovbes.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps" "-L" "/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/release/deps" "-L" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libstd-78187cf09a9bef6f.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libpanic_abort-699459bd9d6c1638.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-397a481a32803af5.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-27eb482dce24475f.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libbacktrace-046a61f77fc212c5.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libbacktrace_sys-8c6fe5218eaa7203.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-4d4d47417516248c.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libunwind-ef8ccbbd42d1b53f.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-bbe68dc13352b6cc.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/liblibc-b6447d8e4c58855b.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/liballoc-3890c13f15229667.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-ceab434c37c7417c.rlib" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libcore-3b2fced4ccf446c5.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-7e358676639674ac.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ladvapi32" "-lws2_32" "-luserenv" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-lgcc_eh" "-lpthread" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "/home/pfemidi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib/rsend.o"
  = note: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.2.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `hello_cargo`.

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name hello_cargo src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C panic=abort -C metadata=3801b83c24480675 -C extra-filename=-3801b83c24480675 --out-dir /home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps --target i686-pc-windows-gnu -C ar=i686-w64-mingw32-ar -C linker=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -L dependency=/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/i686-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps -L dependency=/home/pfemidi/mywork/rust/hello_cargo/target/release/deps` (exit code: 1)
[pfemidi@pfemidi hello_cargo]$
```

Почему так? Что ему не хватает? Где я что-то забыл сделать?

Comment: «*хотя в системе они есть, я проверял и перепроверял уже стопицот раз*» — по старой доброй традиции, многие не верят таким утверждениям, если они не подтверждены выводами из консоли... тем более, что ЕМНИП `mingw` по умолчанию использует нативную реализацию потоков без `pthreads`... собственно попробуй запустить команду линкера вручную без `-lpthread`...

Comment: А смысл запускать вручную? Я проверял, и компилируется, и exe после этого получается работоспособный.

Comment: тогда нужно просто найти где погладить `cargo`/`rustc`, чтобы они `-lpthread` в флаги линкеру не подсовывали...

Comment: Это проще всего, но это last resort к которому очень не хотелось бы прибегать. Смысл как раз в том, чтобы всё работало "из коробки", чтобы проблема решалась не поглаживанием исходников cargo/rustc, а изменением штатных внешних файлов конфигурации.

Comment: думаешь через конфиги это пригладить неудастся?

Comment: ещё, как вариант, можно сделать такой костыль: создать пустую статическую lib'ку с именем `pthread` и кинуть её туда, где mingw её найдёт...

Comment: Я практически всю ночь конфиги гладил и так, и эдак. Не выходит каменный цветок. И пустую lib'ку тоже не хотелось бы ни создавать, ни кидать куда-нибудь, хочется именно "из коробки", чтобы было абсолютно без дополнительных телодвижений ни с дистрибутивом Rust, ни с дистрибутивом mingw, только за счёт конфигов.

Comment: Не пойдёт, увы. В виде "из коробки" не пойдёт. rust сам генерирует объектники, с которыми стандартный mingw из стандартного репозитория Fedora Linux не совместим. Так что или пересобирать rust, научив его генерить знакомые для стандартного линкера из Fedora Linux, или найти именно ту версию mingw, которая уже сейчас совместима с форматом объектников на выходе rust, или воспользоваться [cross](https://crates.io/crates/cross) вместо cargo. Других способов я не вижу.

Comment: Хотя может быть rust "из коробки" будет совместим с mingw "из коробки", не знаю, не проверял (сейчас у меня rust установленный посредством rustup, а rustup в стандартном репозитории Fedora Linux отсутствует, его я брал отдельно).

Comment: «у rust'а из коробки» нет библиотек для целевой системы... так что их всё равно нужно будет собирать... вообще какое-то странное решение у `rustup` предоставлять готовые бинарники только для rust'а целевой платформы, а не средства сборки или весь тулчейн... в бубунте 18.04 проверил на i686'м хосте — там для `i686-w64-mingw32` [не собирается](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bfzVVZM3pN/), а для `x86_64-w64-mingw32` — всё нормально... попробуй им (rustup'у) в багзиллу написать — может что-нить посоветуют...

Comment: Да, "из коробки" нету необходимых библиотек. Ладно, фиг с ним. Я просто надеялся что можно будет обойтись не просто малой кровью, а вообще, так сказать, бескровно, но нет, так не получается.

Answer (score 1):

**Perikl Femidi**, прямого ответа почему у вас ошибки - не дам. Но посоветую стратегию, которую я бы применил для решения вашего вопроса ...

1. Установка набора кросс-компиляторов не в систему, а просто в
   userspace. Просто шикарный вариант - использовать проект [MXE](http://mxe.cc). Пользуюсь я им уже на протяжении 8 лет. Пишу и произвожу отладку, использую Valgrind, в результате получаю исполнимые файлы под восемь целей для M$ Windows.
2. Имея отлаженный набор тулчейнов для кросскомпиляции я бы занялся пропиской всего необходимого инструментария для сборки Rust проектов. В том числе, перед сборкой, я бы поэксперементировал с переменными окружения.

Установить MXE несложно, даю линк на свой блог [(пункт 15)](http://majestio.info/viewtopic.php?id=68). К сожалению, MXE именно под FreeBSD мне так и не удалось установить корректно. Но под дистрибутивами линукса Gentoo, Funtoo, Manjaro все тулчейны MXE работают как швейцарские часики.

Comment: Не, MXE я устанавливать не буду. Мне желателен как можно более "коробочный" вариант.

Comment: Он более чем "коробочный". Отличный поддерживаемый проект.

Comment: "Коробочный" в моём понимании это то, что входит в стандартный репозиторий. MXE увы, не входит.

Comment: Сколько дистров - столько и "коробок". Это не причина отказываться от хорошего решения. ИМХО.

Comment: Я уже сделал для своего Fedora Linux **почти** коробочное решение. Не rpm-based дистрибутивы мне не интересны, а сделав хотя бы для одного rpm-based можно сказать что все rpm-based охвачены, различия между ними минимальны.

Comment: Поспотыкавшись о "коробочные" решения - возвращайтесь к MXE. Просто решите для себя - вам шашечки, или ехать.

Comment: Вот именно что ехать. Сам я сижу **только** в Linux, но мне надо ещё и компилировать `exe` для  Windows, изначально  написанные только на Rust. Так зачем мне огород какой-то городить?

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/489874/) я более-менее популярно рассказал как я решил эту проблему. И никакой [MXE](https://mxe.cc/) ставить не пришлось.

Вот ссылка на аналогичную мою статью [на англоязыкном Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385341/crosscompiling-rust-from-fedora-linux-host-to-windows-target-does-not-find-depen/59455638#59455638)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Я ответил сам себе на свой собственный вопрос. Разве это возбраняется?

Comment: Перечитал. Как автору вопроса мне абсолютно не жалко если мой ответ тут расценят как ответ-ссылку и удалят как низкокачественный, на Хабре он останётся.

Comment: Ну вам-же не сильно сложно тупо сходить в статью на хабре и скопипастить основные тезисы статьи оставив ссылку на оригинал? Кстати, статьи с хабра иногда таки пропадают. Не такие полезные, но тем не менее.

Comment: Там не тезисы придётся копировать, а всю статью. А я её на Хабр и так практически полностью скопировал со своей аналогичной статьи на англоязычном Stackoverflow которую запостил туда ещё в декабре прошлого года. Так зачем получается копировать одно и то же уже в третий раз, когда можно просто оставить ссылку? Тем более на свою же статью, а не на чужую.

Comment: Хабр это внешний ресурс. Вы можете гарантировать, что ссылка через некоторое время не станет показывать в "никуда"? Добавте хотя бы  ссылку на  англ. SO, у неё эта гарантия будет.

Comment: Ссылку на англоязычный SO добавил. Хотя лично у меня доверия к Хабру гораздо больше.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение! Доверие к какому-то ресурсу не имеет ничего общего с гарантией неизменности ссылок на нём. Вы знаете откуда берётся идентификатор вашего поста на Хабре 489874, и вы уверены что он не изменится за всё время существования ресурса Хабр?